# More Efficient Method Substitution than Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, subquery

I have a SQL query where I need to substitute something with another thing in the same table.  I don't know how else to explain it but I will try and provide the general thought I have right now for the SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    ItemCode,
    CASE
        WHEN Name = 'Alpha' THEN (SELECT Name FROM stuff WHERE Name = 'Gama')
        ELSE Name
    END 
FROM <a bunch of joined tables>
```

Sample Data:

```
ItemCode      Name     Location
Itm-1         Alpha    Loc-Alpha
Itm-2         Bravo    Loc-Bavo
Itm-4         Gama     Loc-Gama
```

Desired Results:

```
ItemCode      Name     Location
Itm-1         Gama     Loc-Gama
Itm-2         Bravo    Loc-Bavo
Itm-4         Gama     Loc-Gama
```

I hope that made some sense as I've severely condensed the entire code.  To further complicate things I would use the select subquery multiple times.  Basically I'm trying to avoid using subqueries, which, I believe, extends the execution time due to multiple select statements.  If anyone can provide any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT Name FROM stuff WHERE Name = 'Gama'` will just return `Gama`, if existing. As intended?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.  A tag for the database you are using makes it much easier to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, bare with me as this is my first time as an active inquirer.  Let me figure out how to add sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added sample data and desired results.  I hope this helps.  Let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: Why do you focus on "subquery"? This sounds like a simple lack of experience on your part. But the query you posted does at least half of what you desire - correct? So the only other issue is the replacement in the location column. Correct? Perhaps you have over-simplified and over-complicated things by substituting "alpha" with "gama" while "gama" already exists in your actual data and in desired results. You can use STUFF() to replace strings - a good starting point.

Comment: And one more comment - pseudo-code cannot be "optimized". Still not clear if you have working code that produces the correct output. If you do, you begin the optimization process by examining the execution plan. If you find yourself repeating the same subquery or logic within a query, then perhaps using a join in some fashion (or otherwise materializing that logic) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a `case` expression:

```
SELECT ItemCode,
       (CASE WHEN Name = 'Alpha' THEN 'Gama' ELSE Name END) as name
FROM <a bunch of joined tables>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that I am running MS SQL 2008. (We currently undergoing an upgrade project)  I believe I can use only a CASE statement, but I cannot remember.

Comment: `CASE` is standard SQL and has been supported by SQL Server . . . well, since forever I think.